# Get the list of third-party apps connected to google workspace through API

Tags: go, google-admin-sdk

we're currently using the Reports API in the Admin SDK to get the list of applications that all users hava given access to. To use the API we're using oauth2 tokens and requesting the scopes `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.reports.usage.readonly` and `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.reports.audit.readonly`. Important to note that we're trying to do this for other organizations not inside of our google workspace.

The Admin SDK is already enabled on GCP, and the oauth client and flow is working correctly, as we're getting the access token with the correct scopes, and we can use that token to get the user's profile. We've also checked that the user that did the oauth flow, and whose token we're using, has the correct permissions to access the activities on the Admin console.

Still, when calling the API to get the activities and gather the list of apps, we're getting this error:

`googleapi: Error 401: Access denied. You are not authorized to read activity records., authError`

So my question is, what else could be causing this error?

We know it can be done through domain delegation, and we've tested that flow successfully, but it adds an extra step of configuration that we we're planning to avoid by using oauth scopes. Is there maybe another API or a better way to get the list of apps connected?

This is the code we're using to create the service with the access token obtained from the oauth flow:

```golang
    tokenSource := oauth.StaticTokenSource(
        &oauth.Token{
            AccessToken:  req.OAuthToken,
            RefreshToken: req.OauthRefreshToken,
            TokenType:    "Bearer",
        },
    )
    service, err := admin.NewService(ctx, option.WithTokenSource(tokenSource))
    if err == nil && service != nil {
        return service, nil
    }

    apiActivities, err := service.Activities.List("all", "token").Do()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
```

Comment: One possible cause of the error could be that the user whose token you are using does not have the necessary privileges to access the Reports API. You could try using a super administrator account to see if that resolves the issue.

Another possibility is that the Reports API has not been enabled for your project in the Google Cloud Console. You can check this by going to the API Library in the Google Cloud Console and searching for “Admin SDK” to see if it is enabled.